# Reduction of energy levels of electrons in an atom versus tearing of an atom from electrons

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

From what I understood, when creating Bose–Einstein condensate, electrons are reduced energy levels (transition to other electron shells).
Would stripping an atom of electrons have a similar effect as lowering electron energy states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

To reach the BEC you need to increase phase-space density, which involves losing energy (to get colder) and losing entropy (a BEC is a coherent state with zero entropy).

The *energy* refers to the motional energy of the atoms in the BEC. You want to slow them down. Regardless of the internal electronic state (in principle), provided it adds up to a bosonic state.

The electrons change state when they interact with light. Lasers are shone onto the atoms as part of the cooling mechanisms.